# replacing files in another directory

Tags: bash, shell, directory, cp, binutils

I have two directories structured as follows:

```
dir1/a/file1
dir1/a/b/file2
dir1/a/c/d/file3
```

and

```
dir2/a/file4
dir2/a/b/file5
dir2/a/c/d/file6
```

I want to copy all the files in the subdirectories under dir1 to dir2, but keep the files that are currently in dir2, in other words I want to resulting structure to look like:

```
dir2/a/file1
dir2/a/file4

dir2/a/b/file2
dir2/a/b/file5

dir2/a/c/d/file3
dir2/a/c/d/file6
```

Is there a simple way to do this using bash?

Comment: Doesn't `cp -R` do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with

```
cd dir1 
cp -rpuv * ../dir2/
```

Before:

```
$ find dir2/
dir2/
dir2/a
dir2/a/file4
dir2/a/c
dir2/a/c/d
dir2/a/c/d/file6
dir2/a/b
dir2/a/b/file5
```

After:

```
$ find dir2/
dir2/
dir2/a
dir2/a/file1
dir2/a/file4
dir2/a/c
dir2/a/c/d
dir2/a/c/d/file3
dir2/a/c/d/file6
dir2/a/b
dir2/a/b/file2
dir2/a/b/file5
```

Note that `-p` preserves permissions, `-v` make copy verbose and `-u` only ***updates*** files (doing what the question suggests: *keep the files already in dir2*)